# Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'. Firebase 5 AngularFire2 5

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to create/update shopping-cart in firebase. I am using a service that has functions that add the localStorage ID to firebase and It add's the quantity in shopping-cart if the product already exist otherwise it created new one. The error occurred in console **TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of null** and I also got error on compilation in shopping-cart service.ts:

1. Property 'update' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'.
2. Property 'quantity' does not exist on type '{}'

The following image demonstrate what I'm trying to get in firebase:
[image]

shopping-cart.service.ts

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireDatabase, snapshotChanges } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create(){
    console.log('shoping service')
   return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

 private getCart(cartId: string){
   return this.db.object('/shoping-carts/'+ cartId);
 }

  private async getOrCreateCartId(){
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');

    if(cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;

  }
  private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId).valueChanges();
  }

  async addToCart(product: Product){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);

    item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe( item => {
       item$.update({ product: product, quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
    });
  }
```

shoppng-cart.service.ts (relevant part of document)

```
private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string){
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId).valueChanges();
  }

  async addToCart(product: Product){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);


    item$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe( item => {
       item$.update({ product: product, quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
    });
  }
```

product-card.component.ts

```
import { ShoppingCartService } from './../shopping-cart.service';
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})
export class ProductCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('product') product;
  @Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
  constructor(private cartService:ShoppingCartService) { }

  addToCart(product:Product){
   this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

product-card.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="product.title" class="card m-auto">
    <img class="card-img-top" [src]="product.imageUrl" *ngIf="product.imageUrl" alt="{{ product.title }}">
    <div class="card-body pb-0">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
      <p>{{product.price | currency: 'USD'}}</p>
    </div>
    <div  class="card-footer p-0 border-top">
        <button *ngIf="showActions" (click)="addToCart(product)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

product.ts:

```
export interface Product{
    key:  string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After lot of searching and debugging also part of [Yevgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4662410/yevgen) answer I have modified my code to get rid of **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of null**. If I use `valueChanges` it makes error on new cart addition. So I changed to `snapshotChanges` and put some logic of it's existence and working fine now. If someone still update my answer your're most welcome.

```
private getItem(cartId:string, productId:string) {
  return this.db.object < any > ('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId); 
}

async addToCart(product:Product) {
  let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId(); 
  let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key); 

  item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item:any) =>  {
    if (item.key != null) {
      item$.update( {quantity:( item.payload.val().quantity || 0) + 1}); 
    }
    else{
       item$.set( {product:product, quantity:1}); 
      }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Error is pretty descriptive observable has no such property. Its because `valueChanges()` function returns an observable and it has only data in it. But `AngularFireObject` has update function and you need to use it. So you need to modify your code like:

```
private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string): {
  return this.db.object<any>('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
}

async addToCart(product: Product){
  let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
  let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);

  item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item: any) => {
     item$.update({ product: product, quantity: (item.quantity || 0) + 1});
  });
}
```

Comment: You're right but how about 'item.quantity'?? Still getting the error
Property 'quantity' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: And type any to item inside of subscription (item: any)

Comment: Compile error: Cannot find name 'item'. Did you mean 'item$'?

Comment: Also try to cast return value from firebase like: `object<any>`. Also in edited answer

Comment: I have removed colon from private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string): and type script issues are fixed but while subscribing item returning null and getting error in browser console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180705/discussion-between-azhar-and-yevgen).